# GridView Shocked When Loading Data Get URL Image From Json

Tags: android

I encountered a problem when displaying data from json on the GridView, it is my GridView shock(jerky) when touching the scroll. How to fix this-make it run smoother?
I use the library Picasso to load image from URL  of json.
Here is my Adapter:

```
package com.example.phohay.Adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.phohay.Favorite.Favourite;
import com.example.phohay.com.R;
import com.example.phohay.data.Posts;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class AdapterHome extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Posts> items = new ArrayList<Posts>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Integer[] id;
    Context mContext;
    Boolean isBookMark = false;

    public AdapterHome(Context context, List<Posts> items2) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        items = items2;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        final RelativeLayout Rlayout_imgBook;
        final ImageView imgBookMark;
        TextView tv_View, tv_Name, tv_Comment;

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gridhome, viewGroup, false);

        final Posts post = items.get(i);
        Typeface fontTitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),
                "font/AleoBold.otf");

        picture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgPost);
        tv_Comment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Comment);
        tv_View = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_View);
        tv_Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Name);
        tv_Name.setTypeface(fontTitle);
        imgBookMark = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgBookmark);
        Rlayout_imgBook = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.Rlayout_imgBook);
        // gan gia tri
        // Picasso.with(mContext).load(post.getPost_img().toString())
        // .into(picture);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(post.getPost_img().toString())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.error).error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(picture);
        String Cm = post.getComment().toString();
        int idCm = Integer.parseInt(Cm);
        if (idCm > 1000) {
            int a = idCm / 1000;
            int b = idCm % 1000;
            if (b > 100) {
                int c = b / 100;
                tv_Comment.setText("" + a + "," + c + "k");
            } else {
                tv_Comment.setText("" + a + "k");
            }

        } else {
            tv_Comment.setText(String.valueOf(idCm));
        }
        //tv_Comment.setText(post.getComment().toString());
        String Tv = post.getView().toString();
        int idtv = Integer.parseInt(Tv);
        if (idtv > 1000) {
            int a = idtv / 1000;
            int b = idtv % 1000;
            if (b > 100) {
                int c = b / 100;
                tv_View.setText("" + a + "," + c + "k");
            } else {
                tv_View.setText("" + a + "k");
            }

        } else {
            tv_View.setText(String.valueOf(idtv));
        }
        //tv_View.setText(post.getView().toString());
        tv_Name.setText(post.getTitle().toString());
        // Rlayout_imgBook

        // gan gia tri favotite
        post.setIsFavorite(Favourite.isFavourited(Integer.parseInt(post
                .getPost_id())));

        if (post.getIsFavorite()) {
            Rlayout_imgBook.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#55F73667"));
            imgBookMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);
        } else {
            Rlayout_imgBook.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#55000000"));
            imgBookMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
        }
        //
        imgBookMark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                post.setIsFavorite(!post.getIsFavorite());

                if (post.getIsFavorite()) {
                    Rlayout_imgBook.setBackgroundColor(Color
                            .parseColor("#55F73667"));
                    imgBookMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);
                    Favourite.favourite(Integer.parseInt(post.getPost_id()));
                    // isBookMark = true;
                } else {
                    Rlayout_imgBook.setBackgroundColor(Color
                            .parseColor("#55000000"));
                    imgBookMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
                    Favourite.removeFavourite(Integer.parseInt(post
                            .getPost_id()));
                    // isBookMark = false;
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}
package com.example.phohay.Adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.phohay.Favorite.Favourite;
import com.example.phohay.com.R;
import com.example.phohay.data.Posts;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class AdapterHome extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Posts> items = new ArrayList<Posts>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Integer[] id;
    Context mContext;
    Boolean isBookMark = false;

    public AdapterHome(Context context, List<Posts> items2) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        items = items2;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        final RelativeLayout Rlayout_imgBook;
        final ImageView imgBookMark;
        TextView tv_View, tv_Name, tv_Comment;

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gridhome, viewGroup, false);

        final Posts post = items.get(i);
        Typeface fontTitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),
                "font/AleoBold.otf");

        picture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgPost);
        tv_Comment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Comment);
        tv_View = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_View);
        tv_Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Name);
        tv_Name.setTypeface(fontTitle);
        imgBookMark = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgBookmark);
        Rlayout_imgBook = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.Rlayout_imgBook);
        // gan gia tri
        // Picasso.with(mContext).load(post.getPost_img().toString())
        // .into(picture);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(post.getPost_img().toString())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.error).error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(picture);
        String Cm = post.getComment().toString();
        int idCm = Integer.parseInt(Cm);
        if (idCm > 1000) {
            int a = idCm / 1000;
            int b = idCm % 1000;
            if (b > 100) {
                int c = b / 100;
                tv_Comment.setText("" + a + "," + c + "k");
            } else {
                tv_Comment.setText("" + a + "k");
            }

        } else {
            tv_Comment.setText(String.valueOf(idCm));
        }
        //tv_Comment.setText(post.getComment().toString());
        String Tv = post.getView().toString();
        int idtv = Integer.parseInt(Tv);
        if (idtv > 1000) {
            int a = idtv / 1000;
            int b = idtv % 1000;
            if (b > 100) {
                int c = b / 100;
                tv_View.setText("" + a + "," + c + "k");
            } else {
                tv_View.setText("" + a + "k");
            }

        } else {
            tv_View.setText(String.valueOf(idtv));
        }
        //tv_View.setText(post.getView().toString());
        tv_Name.setText(post.getTitle().toString());
        // Rlayout_imgBook

        // gan gia tri favotite
        post.setIsFavorite(Favourite.isFavourited(Integer.parseInt(post
                .getPost_id())));

        if (post.getIsFavorite()) {
            Rlayout_imgBook.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#55F73667"));
            imgBookMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);
        } else {
            Rlayout_imgBook.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#55000000"));
            imgBookMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
        }
        //
        imgBookMark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                post.setIsFavorite(!post.getIsFavorite());

                if (post.getIsFavorite()) {
                    Rlayout_imgBook.setBackgroundColor(Color
                            .parseColor("#55F73667"));
                    imgBookMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);
                    Favourite.favourite(Integer.parseInt(post.getPost_id()));
                    // isBookMark = true;
                } else {
                    Rlayout_imgBook.setBackgroundColor(Color
                            .parseColor("#55000000"));
                    imgBookMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
                    Favourite.removeFavourite(Integer.parseInt(post
                            .getPost_id()));
                    // isBookMark = false;
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}
```

thank any help yet!
G9.

Comment: GridView shock  what is it mean?

Comment: @Nithinlal when I touch scroll to load more items in the grid, it does not run smoothly (like when I load the image from drawable), it was jerky and hard to claw srcoll
You can help me?

Comment: what this code does `final Posts post = items.get(i);`, is it by any chance getting data by doing network operation?

Comment: @KaranMer Post is a object I creat to save data from json, it includes the string(name, value,url...) . I use MyAsyncTask to load data and then i used string url from data to load ImageView.

Comment: are you on low speed internet connection? are images that you are loading big in size?

Comment: @KaranMer I do not think like that, when building it by ios or windowphone ,it running smoothly. Was it due to my phone's memory image small or not loading properly?

Comment: still did you checked on faster connection? also make sure your images are not too large

Comment: try doing it like this first get the url in a String object `String temp = post.getPost_img().toString();` and then use picasso like  `Picasso.with(mContext).load(temp)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.error).error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(picture);`

Comment: @KaranMer it is still the same! Is there a way to load images before the set adapter for GridView?

Comment: post the updated code. also if possible post some images or a video would be great

Comment: @Trần Văn Hòa to solve the issue we have to find which causes this issue. first should comment the image binding option from the adapter and check GridView work properly. Then we can move to solve the issue

Comment: I have tried many different ways such as using other libraries (ImageLoader), LazyLoader (reduced image size and saved in memory) but it only reduces the phenomenon of the GridView lag a little.

Comment: I have done it.
Simply remove font in method getview() and create it in fragment.
I do not understand why, but it seems useful to me.
Thank you for your interest both my questions!
Good luck for you!